# How long does it take to ubuntu 12.10 reboot after installation?

Tags: installation, 12.10

Im stuck on a screen after installing 12.10 ubuntu heres exactly what it says.

`Welcome to Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-17-generic i686)

   * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

ubuntuAubuntu:~$
Broadcast message from root@ubuntu

   (unknown) at 19:23 ...

The system is going to reboot NOW!`

That is exactly what my screen says it hasn't rebooted in over 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes,users face this problem.Normally, it takes a couple of seconds.I think, you can power-off manually then can start it.They wouldn't cause problems.There is nothing else you can.
I don't think,but If you face some problems after manual reboot(like critical errors),most probably you will have to install ubuntu again.